# High chart array formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I have an array which gives output as the below. Have to make a new key value pair

```
var obj = [
{
Title: "North America",
Value: 66457682.57055664,
Year: [
{Value: 11061419.089111328, Year: 2017},
{Value: 11039525.639892578, Year: 2018},
{Value: 11040422.410644531, Year: 2019}
]},
{Title: "USA",
Value: 66457682.57055664,
Year: [
{Value: 11454419.089111328, Year: 2017},
{Value: 11456.639892578, Year: 2018},
{Value: 11056562.410644531, Year: 2019}
]}]
```

how do i get the array in this format in jQuery ?

```
var year = [2017,2018,2019];

var data = [
{

name:North America
data:[11061419.089111328,11039525.639892578,11056562.410644531]
},
{
name:USA
data:[11061419.034328,13439525.6343478,1167672.4106761]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform your arrays (without jQuery).

```js
var rawData = [{
    Title: "North America",
    Value: 66457682.57055664,
    Year: [{
        Value: 11061419.089111328,
        Year: 2017
      },
      {
        Value: 11039525.639892578,
        Year: 2018
      },
      {
        Value: 11040422.410644531,
        Year: 2019
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Title: "USA",
    Value: 66457682.57055664,
    Year: [{
        Value: 11454419.089111328,
        Year: 2017
      },
      {
        Value: 11456.639892578,
        Year: 2018
      },
      {
        Value: 11056562.410644531,
        Year: 2019
      }
    ]
  }
];

var years = rawData[0].Year.map(({Year}) => Year);
console.log(years);

var data = rawData.map(({Title, Year}) => ({
  name: Title,
  data: Year.map(y => y.Value)
}));
console.log(data);
```